# Boolean doesn't work?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to use the difference mode to make a hole.

[image]

But when I select Difference and the object it does this?

[image]

I removed all the doubles and recalculated normals on both objects but it still does this?

Blend file
[image]

Comment: It is hard to see what are your objects before the boolean operation. Could you share the initial file here (before the boolean applied) ? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry, heres the file: 
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1499" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1499/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a scale / normals problem : your objects scales were negative.

I applied rotations and scales <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then adjusted the normals (in edit mode <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> for both objects).

Then your model is ready for the boolean (difference) : [image]

Answer (score -2):

There is also a couple add-ons to fall back on if regular Boolean does not work. These are 'Booltool' and 'Booltron'

Comment: Please add some steps as to *how* these add-ons help vs a normal boolean and what features of these add-ons need to be operated.