# Boolean intersect with plane makes object disappear

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'ts been 10 hours of researching, watching tutorials, trial and error and yet i still cannot figure this out.

I have 2 planes, one being my water for my city and the other being the ground. I'm trying to intersect the water with the ground so it will make a little divot like in the image below but every time I do that the mesh disappears or it won't allow me to even intersect it with the Bboolean modifier.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, removing doubles, making the ground a cube instead of a plane and yet none of these work.

I'll upload the file below but this is just the current lake I've tried out of the 200 other attempts.

The tutorial I'm following is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4ySFm4ey9U&list=LLZKTEq5R9PWrJvExEVHgTFg&index=5

At 55:36 mark is where I'm stuck.

If anyone could help it would be very appreciated thank you for your time :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why delete the previous question and re-post? Please just edit the original one.

Comment: I'm sorry I will for future posts, just frustrated that I sitl haven't figured this out

Comment: You can't intersect with planes, Boolean operations require closed manifold shapes to be able to work, water planes have no volume just a single "sheet" and thus can't be used in a Boolean operation. Try adding some volume by extruding it so an intersection boundary can be found

Answer (score 4):

First. The scale of your plane is set to negative.

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in object mode and select apply scale.

Then the river object has inverted normals.

[image]

Make them consistent by pressing ctrl N

[image]

Booleans use the direction of the normals to calculate the operation.

Then use Difference to cut out the shape of the river out of the plane:

[image]

Some reasons for failed booleans operations:

- [Non-Manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/1853)
- [Inconsistent normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50632/1853)
- [Booleans don't work with curves or text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27151/1853)
- [The scale for the object uses negative values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56587/boolean-doesnt-work)

Comment: Thank you so much cegaton. I seriously appreciate your time and effort with my frustration. Cheers and best of luck with everything <3 You seriously made my day.